# What is the minecraft armor equation

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know minecraft armor and that half a armour bar stops 4% of the damage. But I dont quite understand how the equation is done. If someone could comment an example that would be great.!(Like the equation but answer it like you have diamond armour and a diamond sword)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Armor#Mechanics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Official Minecraft Wiki gives an exact formula of how damage is applied:

[image]

However, this formula is only applicable to Java editions of Minecraft.

If you are on Bedrock, then each defense point provides a flat 4% damage reduction. For example, in Bedrock, standard leather armor gives a flat 28% damage protection.